# MySql exception Unable to serialize date/time value when using DateTimeOffset.UtcNow

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, openiddict

I'm using EF6 on .net framework 4.8 and Oracle's mysql-connector-net provider (v8.0.23 of the MySql.Data and MySql.Data.EntityFramework nuget packages)

Consider this code

```
DateTimeOffset threshold = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
List<Domain.Entities.Security.openiddicttoken> query = await _dbContext.openiddicttokens.Where(token => token.CreationDate < threshold.UtcDateTime).ToListAsync();
```

Using this class

```
public partial class openiddicttoken {
    ///...other properties
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

The field in the DB is:

```
  `ExpirationDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Produces this exception (top part, I omitted the async part information):

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
> occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
> exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:
> Fatal error encountered during command execution. --->
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to serialize date/time
> value.
> at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket
> packet, Boolean binary, Object value, Int32 length)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection
> parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)

The exception seems to be thrown only if I use the `UtcDateTime` of a DateTimeOffset. If I use threshold`.DateTime`, it seems to work fine.
Strange things is that both properties return a DateTime type.

The problem for me is that this code is part of a package (openiddict), so I cannot change the C# code. I can only change the nuget package versions, and the DB layout.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I'm guessing the expression parser doesn't work because `threshold` is a `DateTimeOffset` (not because of the property). Can you try extracting the `UtcDateTime` property to a variable -outside the `Where` expression- and use that variable in the `Where`, instead of specifically using `threshold.UtcDateTime`?

Comment: Meaning: `var thresholdTime = threshold.UtcDateTime; blablabla.Where(token => token.CreationDate < thresholdTime).ToListAsync()`

Comment: Jcl, your suggestion seems to work in this example (even though I have no idea why the value isn't evaluated earlier.  I guess it's the way EF works). So thanks for that. But unfortunately, as indicated in my last phrase, I cannot update the c# code. The code is actually part of the openiddict package. I'll see if I can get some help there.

Comment: The problem is that the MySQL driver doesn't understand `DateTimeOffset` at all, so it doesn't know how to parse the expression on `Where` when it finds one. I'm not sure if it's the same driver, but this was fixed on [this one](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/845) at some point. Probably not on Oracle's (as it may seem now), or maybe not for EF6. But that's just a guess, I haven't worked with any of them.